# Function not calling and how to wait for click in tkinter loop

Tags: python, multithreading, loops, button, tkinter

I've hit a dead end at the moment - firstly when you click one of the dynamic buttons, the function call is made, and it does return the name of the button clicked. However the `fEndDay` function it's supposed to call as well doesn't appear to run.

EDIT: The day is now running. Just relaunched Liclipse and it started working. No explanation. However, the button wait issue remains.

I'm also a little stuck at the moment. In essence I want:

- While current day < total days....

  - Run a daily event, updating the screen objects.
  - Take a choice via button click.
  - Increase the current day.

However, the day loop stops the screen from displaying (i.e. processing loop). I guess if there's code that pushes the object display up and sits in an infinate loop, which is broken by the button click, that would do. Other ideas? Current code below.

```
#!/usr/bin/python

# Reminder to self - lots to add. Include a function to reset the text content
# and populate with day number, score summary etc as a template. We can then
# add to it.



#################### IMPORT MODULES WE NEED ############################
import time                     # For sleep delays
from random import randint      # for random numbers
from _ast import While          # while loops
import tkinter as Tkinter       # this one handles windows and buttons etc
from tkinter import *           # skip the tkinter prefix (constants etc)
# import tkmessagebox  # Python 2 alternative!
from tkinter import messagebox as tkMessageBox # Python 3
import sys                      # for quit when added ie  sys.exit()  
from functools import partial   # So we can create lists of buttons & commands
import time                     # threading support - check events while waiting
import concurrent.futures       # threading - think i'll be needing all this





################## CREATE A NEW CLASS (CONTAINER) ############################
class CrazyCoder (Tkinter.Tk):
    # When the class is created, the function fInitialise is run, below.
    def __init__(self,parent):
        Tkinter.Tk.__init__(self,parent)
        self.parent = parent
        self.fInitialize()  # State here any functions to run on creation





    ################################ FUNCTION ################################
    # Set up variables etc...
    def fInitialize(self):


        ########################### VARIABLES ###############################
        # Overkill here probably but will revisit later! Listed / initialised  
        # here to simplify searching later on!
        # Could pass most of theses but will keep it simple and update globally
        # to start with
        self.vDayNumber = 1     # What the current day is
        self.vFinalDay = 10     # The last day of our game
        self.vPlayerName = ''   # To hold the players name
        self.vGameName = ''     # To hold the game name
        self.vChoice = ''       # To hold the user choices clicked
        self.vRandom = 0        # To hold random numbers!
        self.vGameplay = 0      # SCORES: Current gameplay score
        self.vGraphics = 0      # SCORES:  Current graphics score
        self.vSound = 0         # SCORES:  current sound score
        self.vBugs = 0          # SCORES:  current bug score'
        self.vBackColor = 'grey'    # The background colour of our app
        self.vDynamic_Buttons = []  # To hold button objects each "screen"
        self.vEntryBox = []         # To hold text entry box objects
        self.vTextEntry = ''        # Stores user text entry value temporarily
        self.vAvailableButtons = [] # To hold a list of AVAILABLE buttons/event


        ########################## APP SETUP ################################
        self.title('Crazy Coder')                # set window title
        self.geometry("500x500")                    # set screen size
        self.configure(background=self.vBackColor)  # set background colour

        # Add a "Title box"
        self.vTitle = Tkinter.Label(self,text='Crazy Coder')
        self.vTitle.configure(background=self.vBackColor)
        self.vTitle.pack(side=TOP,padx=10,pady=10)

        # Add a picture box (gif supported)
        self.vImage =     PhotoImage(file="PUG.gif")
        self.vPicture=Label(self,image=self.vImage)
        self.vPicture.image=self.vImage
        self.vPicture.pack()

        # Add the main text box 
        self.vMessageText = '''
        This is where your day number goes
        Scores go here too
        Event details go here too'''
        self.vMessage = Tkinter.Label(self,text=self.vMessageText)
        self.vMessage.configure(background=self.vBackColor) 
        self.vMessage.pack(side=TOP,padx=10,pady=10)


        # While loop does not work - there is no concept of
        # "display current buttons / screen and wait for click event"

        #while self.vDayNumber <= self.vFinalDay:

        self.vChoice = '' # Clear it ready to take a user choice each day

        print('DEBUG: On Main screen, starting now')    


        self.vRandom = randint(1,100)

        if self.vDayNumber == 1:
            self.fWelcomeScreen()   # Set up the welcome screen
        elif self.vRandom >= 0:
            self.fEvent1()          # Kick off event 1







    ############################# FUNCTION ################################# 
    # Sets the message on the main text box to whatever you put in brackets
    def fSetText(self,TextMessage):
        global vMessageText                 
        self.vMessageText = TextMessage      
        self.vMessage['text'] = self.vMessageText # This updates the text box




    ############################# FUNCTION ################################# 
    # Sets the image on the main picture box to whatever you put in brackets
    def fSetImage(self,ImageName):
        global vImage
        self.vImage = PhotoImage(file=ImageName) # Example "PUG2.gif"
        self.vPicture['image']=self.vImage        # This updates the image box 




    ############################# FUNCTION ################################# 
    # Add a new Entry box to our screen. Supports multiple uses
    def fAddEntryBox(self):
        self.vNewBox = Entry(width=20)
        self.vEntryBox.append(self.vNewBox)
        self.vNewBox.pack(side=TOP,padx=10,pady=10)    
        self.vNewBox.focus()




    ############################# FUNCTION ################################# 
    # Remove the Entry Boxes
    def fDeleteEntryBoxes(self):
        for each_box in self.vEntryBox:
            each_box.destroy()




    ############################# FUNCTION ################################# 
    # Read from the requested box number, cutting off the Enter at the end 
    def fReadEntryBox(self,BoxNumber): #BoxNumber 0 is the first box, 1 next
        global vTextEntry
        vTextEntry=self.vEntryBox[BoxNumber].get()




    ############################# FUNCTION ################################# 
    # Handles the the day passing by
    def fEndDay(self):
        global vPlayerName, vDayNumber
        self.vDayNumber = self.vDayNumber + 1    
        print("This print isn't running either!")





    ############################# FUNCTION ################################# 
    # A simple step to take a choice from the user - used for button code below
    def fMakeChoice(self,value): 
        global vChoice, vDayNumber
        self.fEndDay()
        self.vChoice = value
        print('Just Clicked:',self.vChoice, "and it's day ", self.vDayNumber)
        print('But fEndDay should have just run and increased it to 2!')





    ############################# FUNCTION ################################# 
    # Add buttons to the screen, based on vAvailableButtons 
    def fAddButtons(self): 
        global vAvailableButtons # Shouldn't need this here but...
        for each_button in self.vAvailableButtons:
            # Important: the Lambda section takes the CURRENT value of the variable 
            # and stores is in the command string. Without it, all the buttons
            # when clicked would do the same as the last button created! daft eh.
            vNewButton = Tkinter.Button(self, text=each_button, command=lambda v=each_button: self.fMakeChoice(v))
            self.vDynamic_Buttons.append(vNewButton)
            vNewButton.pack(side= BOTTOM, padx = 10, pady = 10)





    ############################# FUNCTION ################################# 
    # Clear the buttons out ie before drawing new ones
    def fDeleteButtons(self):
        for each_button in self.vDynamic_Buttons:
            each_button.destroy()




    ############################# FUNCTION ################################# 
    # Pop up message box
    def fMessage(self,Message):
        self.tkMessageBox.showinfo("News", Message)    




    #*********************************************************************# 
    #*********************    EVENTS SECTION   ***************************# 
    #*********************************************************************# 
    # We'll define a function here for each "daily event"
    # The section will be responsible for:
    #    1) Updating the screen image (if necessary)
    #    2) Updating the text box content 
    #    3) Adding entry boxes and buttons as required
    #    4) Ending the day (there will be one decision per day for now)



    ############################# EVENT ################################# 
    # The welcome screen
    def fWelcomeScreen(self):
        global vAvailableButtons
        self.vTextMessage = '''
        Yawn. You wake up.
        Whats your name?
        '''
        self.fSetText(self.vTextMessage)
        time.sleep(1)   # delays for 1 second
        self.fAddEntryBox()  # Add an entry box for a name
        self.vAvailableButtons = ['Ok']
        self.fAddButtons()   # vChoice set on click, and day ended



    ############################# EVENT ################################# 
    # A random event
    def fEvent1(self):
        global vAvailableButtons
        self.vTextMessage = '''
        This is an event. What will you do?
        '''
        self.fSetText(self.vTextMessage)
        time.sleep(1)   # delays for 1 second
        self.vAvailableButtons = ['Ok']
        self.fAddButtons()   # vChoice set on click, and day ended




# Start the program    
if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = CrazyCoder(None)
    app.mainloop()
```

Comment: How do I scrap a question? Or do I leave it here for reference in case anyone else finds use for the code?

Comment: - The first issue vanished by itself. Since the day incremented, I found the simplest solution for the "wait" is to simply have a call to a "fNewDay" new function in the button click event - once the event is handled I can then randomly select a new event, and present it etc.

Answer (score 0):

The fact that you want to run some function once a day is no different than wanting an animation to run 30 frames per second. You effectively want an "animation" that runs 1 fpd (one frame per day).

The way to accomplish that is to create a function that should run once a day.

```
def do_once_a_day():
    ...
```

Next, create a function that will call that function once a day:

```
def call_daily(self):
    self.do_once_a_day()
    if self.vDayNumber <= self.vFinalDay:
        root.after(1000*60*60*24, self.call_daily)
```

This will cause `do_once_a_day` to be called once every 24 hours. You can then do whatever you want inside that function.

Comment: Thanks Brian - I didn't need it to run once a day. The program just simulates days passing as events happen.

Comment: I was undere the illusion that I had to "wait for a button click" in a loop. The mainloop however sufficed - all I needed to do was trigger the "new day" processing on the button click event ;)

Comment: @user4105741: there is no need to "wait" for a button click. The call to `mainloop` puts the application in a perpetual state of waiting for events.